# Bars on D3 Bar Graph not showing up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I've been staring at this code for hours now and maybe it's obvious or just needs a fresh set of eyes, but I am desperate to figure out why the bars on the graph aren't showing up??

Here is the fiddle for it: 
http://jsfiddle.net/u7zs3jwo/1/

Here's the JSON:

```
var bardata = [
   {
      "ts":1431728734,
      "interval":12,
      "method":"GET",
      "host":"beta.familysearch.org",
      "aggs":{    
         "con":{     //Connect
            "25":6,
            "50":6,
            "75":6,
            "90":7.1,
            "95":7.55,
            "99":7.91,
            "mn":6,
            "mx":8,
            "avg":6.3,
            "stddv":0.67
         },
         "count":10,
         "srvbsy":{     
            "25":2100.75,
            "50":2272,
            "75":3038.25,
            "90":3571.4,
            "95":3627.2,
            "99":3671.84,
            "mn":920,
            "mx":3683,
            "avg":2452.6,
            "stddv":836.3
         }
      }
   }
];
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Very strange place for the loop. It looks like you're looping through the data and creating an SVG for each and transitioning this SVG etc. for each data item.... is that the intent?

Comment: When passing data to d3, it would be best to use an array of objects. Also, it is unclear from your data how the final bar chart should look like. What values should be plotted, and what should not?

Comment: @Alex_B Whoops! I forgot to get rid of the loop.  I only attached one part of the full array (the full array has 50+ copies of what is shown above).  The intent is to go through all 50 of the srvbsy.mx and plot all of them on the same chart.  I thought if I could at least get one value on there, then I would be able to get the other 50 by looping through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data passed in to D3 must be in the form of an array. As your code stands you are passing in a single value. I am answering with the assumption that you only want to plot a single bar, the value of 'mx'.

Simply by changing your code like below, the line shows up.

Change the value passed in to be an array.

```
bardata = {
    ...
    "mx":[3683],
    ...
}
```

And change the scale function to use the first index of the 'mx' array.

```
var vGuideScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, bardata[i].aggs.srvbsy.mx[0]]) // <-- here
    .range([height, 0])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7zs3jwo/2/